# T-SQL Server ORDER BY date and nulls last

Tags: case

I am studying for exam 70-761 and there is a challenge asking to place nulls in the end when using order by, I know the result is this one:

select 
orderid,
shippeddate
from Sales.Orders
where custid = 20
order by case when shippeddate is null then 1 else 0 end, shippeddate

what i don't know is why the 1 and 0 and how they affect the result can anyone clarify.

Best Regards,
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

There are two parameters in your order clause, it like to split two groups and then continue sort items inside those groups

First, because 0 less than 1, so all the orders without shippeddate will be push to last. 
Then we will order by shippeddate
Example:

orderID | shippeddate

1. | null
2. | today
3. | null
4. | yesterday
5. | tomorrow

First sort by `case when shippeddate is null then 1 else 0 end` we will got

orderID | shippeddate

2. | today
3. | yesterday
4. | tomorrow
5. | null
6. | null

then continue sort with shippeddate, we will got

4. | yesterday
5. | today
6. | tomorrow
7. | null
8. | null

---

hope it useful to you

Comment: I kinda of understood.

Comment: would appreciate another explanation :)